# How to skip already copied files in Azure data factory, copy data tool?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I want to copy data from blob storage(parquet format) to cosmos db. Scheduled the trigger for every one hour. But all the files/data getting copied in every run. how to skip the files that are already copied?

There is no unique key with the data. We should not copy the same file content again.

Comment: Is your blob data not organised into a timestamped file structure?  If it was, you could schedule your copy to be run after a time boundary (eg: at 5 mins past the hour) to copy everything in the pervious hour's folder.

Comment: What is that "Filter by last modified" in Source dataset?

Comment: @Udhaya Hi,if my answer helps you,could you mark it for answer? If not, please let me help you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirements, you could get an idea of `modifiedDatetimeStart` and `modifiedDatetimeEnd` properties in [Blob Storage DataSet properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#dataset-properties).

[image]

But you need to modify the configuration of dataset every period of time via [sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-dot-net#create-a-dataset) to push the value of the properties move on.

Another two solutions you could consider :

1.Using [Blob Trigger Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function).It could be triggered if any modifications on the blob files then you could transfer data from blob to cosmos db by sdk code.

2.Using [Azure Stream Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/stream-analytics/).You could configure the [input as Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-inputs#stream-data-from-blob-storage) and [output as Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-documentdb-output).